# c# button click changing other class string value

Tags: c#

i need a bit of help with my code if anyone is willing to help me. my code looks like this.
button code ---

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   character tom = new character();
            pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[2];
            tom.location = "Forest";
            label10.Text = tom.location;
}
```

im trying to turn tom.locations value into Forest after the button press but after i used the debugger it showed me the tom.location is still the default value that i set. what am i doing wrong?
tom

```
public int currenthp = 50;
        public string name; 
        public bool whileCombat = true;
        public int level = 1;
        public int strength = 10;
        public int gold = 0;
        public int xp;
        public int totallevel;
        public int damage2;
        public int potion = 3;
        public int escape2;
        public bool alive = true;
        public string location = "";
```

Comment: Share your code. The class of the object tom.

Comment: How about tom.location() method ?

Comment: ahh dang my bad those () shouldnt have been there it was one of my little tests to get the code working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You did't get a error when you debugged this code? I am not very sure of that, you can't call to ***tom.localitation***, without a method of the Class *Tom*.

You can do a method of the *class Tom*, or declarare a *static variable*, I recommend you the static variable.

```
public static string localitation = "";
```

Comment: huh cool it worked i changed the location to static and changed the button click to  character.location = "Forest"; now the code works thanks